# Callback was already called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

When I try to use list.forEach method in async.waterfall in node.js, I've got the error message: 
if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");

Error: Callback was already called.

What I want is to do some changes to every files in a directory.

```
/**
 * Created by slow_time on 2017/3/22.
 */
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var _dir = './data/';
//writeStream is used to log something
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt',
    {
        'flags': 'a',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'mode': 0666
    });

try {
    //use the method waterfall
    async.waterfall([
        //read the directory
        function (callback) {
            fs.readdir(_dir, function (err, files) {
                callback(err, files);
            });
        },
        function (files, callback) {
            //Here is what I guess, something wrong with it
            files.forEach(function (name) {
                callback(null, name);
            });
        },
        //The code below is right, I think.
        function (file, callback) {
            fs.stat(_dir + file, function (err, stats) {
                if(stats.isFile())
                    callback(err, stats, file);
            });
        },
        //judge whether it is a file or a directory
        function (stats, file, callback) {
            fs.readFile(_dir + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                callback(err, file, data);
            });
        },
        // do some changes to the file content
        function (file, data, callback) {
            var adjData = data.replace(/somecompany\.com/g, 'burningbird.net');
            fs.writeFile(_dir + file, adjData, function (err) {
                callback(err, file);
            });
        },
        //write the changes back to the file
        function (file, callback) {
            writeStream.write('changed ' + file + '\n', 'utf8', function (err) {
                callback(err, file);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('modified ' + result);
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: on which line your getting error ?

Comment: You can't use `async.waterfall` to run code for each element in a list like that. You'll need to use [`async.map`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map).

Comment: Thanks, first. What you mean is that I can never use forEach method in async.waterfall? But it is a demo in a book. And how to use async.map in my situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Async: Callback already called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461736/nodejs-async-callback-already-called)

Answer (score 3):

As you are calling callback in foreach its giving error.
Your code -

```
files.forEach(function (name) {
   callback(null, name);
});
```

callback should be call only once after you are completed your operations.
So do this changes:

```
files.forEach(function (name) {

});
callback(null, name);
```

Comment: If I change my to what you suggest, I can't go through all the files in the list

Comment: then you can use promise to aceive this. like foreach().then(callback)

Comment: or you can use this async appraoch :-                                         async.each(items,
  // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
  function(item, callback){
    // Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
    callback();
  },
  // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
  function(err){
    // All tasks are done now
    console.log("done")
  }
);